# Import error in the src folder, so I can't run the dataProcess.py file

Tags: python

The structure of my code is as follows:

```
spcript
    src
        __init__.py
        integration_site
        __init__.py
            integrationSite.py
        integration_zoom_buscape
         __init__.py
            dataProcess.py
```

I'm trying to run the dataProcess.py file, but I get the following error message:

```
from src.integration_site.integrationSite import IntegrationWithWebSite
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I was hoping to run the dataProcess.py file, but I'm getting an import error